# Differences between the control structures php and control structures javascript

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement

You know what are the differences between the control structure in Javascript and control structure in PHP? 
Both use the if / else, for or while, but that vary in that change?

Are two different programming languages ​​but there are differences in the part of "control structure" in the syntax although both are similar.

Examples

Javascript control structure

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 5;
    var b = 8;

    if (a < b)
    {
        alert(a +" is smaller than " +b);
    }

</script>
```

PHP control structure

```
<?php
    // Number comparison
    $a = 5;
    $b = 8;

    if ($a < $b)
    {
        echo $a ."is smaller than" .$b;
    }                
    // Result : 5 is smaller than 8
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Already one running server side and the other is from the browser, interests me is from the side of the control structure, which is if, for, while and others

Comment: Your condition is incorrect to begin with. It should be `<` and not `<=` if you want to trigger it when a is smaller than b

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Friend what are the examples illustrated

Answer (score 2):

Öhm, there are many big differences. The most important thing is that `JavaScript` runs on client side through your browser and `PHP` runs on server side. For PHP you need a webserver with a PHP module to understand that type of script.

PHP code stays on the server. If you ran your PHP side the server will send you the through PHP generated HTML. The JavaScript code will be send together with this HTML to the client/Browser and after it it will be called...

With PHP you can read your Database. With JavaScript (client-side) you can make an AJAX call to your server where a PHP script reads your Database and returns the data. **Update:** But JavaScript could also run server-side and then read your Database.

PHP is often used to generate HTML. JavaScript is often used to manipulate/animate HTML.

Comment: This is just plain wrong: JavaScript can run server-side, too. It's a very portable language, which can be used to query the DB just fine. Some NoSQL databases even use JavaScript for queryies (couchbase, mongodb...). JS by itself ***can't manipulate HTML***, the client-side implementations implement the DOM API for that, which is not part of JS

Answer (score 1):

In this case, there is no difference. Both operands are numeric (JS `Number` type, PHP `int`'s). The difference is JS's type coercion, and how certain values are represented internally (all numbers are 64bit IEEE-754 floats, PHP distinguished between floats (which are actually doubles) and ints (which are actually of the C type `long`). Both languages use lazy evaluation (`if (false && <expression2>)` will not evaluate the second expression). Google the PHP truth tables so see some special oddities like `"0"` being false, whereas `'0'` is true.

Check the PHP truth tables [here](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Note that the idea that JS is restricted to run client-side is just plain wrong. JS is a very small, highly portable language. it runs server-side (node.js), it runs on DB's (mongoDB, couchbase), it is used as a scripting language in other programs (most adobe software), on domestic appliances like smart-TV's... its the most common programming language in the world.
This is because JavaScript does **not** have IO capabilities (IO methodologies differ depending on how/where the code runs). To generate output, JS uses API's. In a browser, it uses the DOM API, which is not gouverned by ECMA, but by W3C. It's not part of JavaScript.

Comment: +1 For these exact explanation